# Creating a column based on existing column where new column has values plus or minus certain value of old one

Tags: r

I am trying to create a column, where the new column has values plus or minus some fixed number or existing number of old column. For example, my old column is `a` and new column is `b`.

```r
data = data.frame(a = 2:11)
new_data = data.frame(a = 2:11, b = c(1, 4, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9, 8, 11, 12))
new_data
#>     a  b
#> 1   2  1
#> 2   3  4
#> 3   4  5
#> 4   5  5
#> 5   6  6
#> 6   7  8
#> 7   8  9
#> 8   9  8
#> 9  10 11
#> 10 11 12
```

Comment: @AnilGoyal It can have same number also.

Comment: Did the revised answer serve the purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data$b <- data$a + sample(c(0, -1, +1), nrow(data), replace = T)
```

so If fixed number is say `x` do this

```
x <- 1
data$b <- data$a + sample(c(0, -1*x, x), nrow(data), replace = T)
```

**Edit** based on requirements stated in comments below.  Use `pmin` and `pmax`.  seed fixed in order to demonstrate

```
set.seed(19)
data %>% mutate(b = pmin(11, pmax(2, a + sample(-1:1, nrow(.), T)))) %>% pull(b) %>% cat

2 3 4 6 5 7 7 10 9 11

#otherwise
set.seed(19)
data %>% mutate(b = a + sample(-1:1, nrow(.), T))

   a  b
1   2  1
2   3  3
3   4  4
4   5  6
5   6  5
6   7  7
7   8  7
8   9 10
9  10  9
10 11 12
```

Comment: ```data %>% mutate(b = a + sample(c(-1, 0, 1), nrow(data), replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  select("a1") %>% cat``` is not working. I would like to display all the values of new column in a single row. Any suggestions?

Comment: ```sample(1:10, 10, replace = T) %>% cat``` so all the numbers are in a single row.

Comment: I found the trick. We need to unlist and use cat. ```unlist %>% cat```

Comment: Can we restrict the numbers generated between 2 and 11 (including) in the new column? Because of this addition some numbers become 1, some become 12. Desired output is all 1's remain as 2 and all 12's remain as 11. Is there a way?

Comment: see edited.  perhaps it should serve the purpose now